# switching xml layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

what is going wrong here? for some reason I want to switch the xml layout from one java class to the other java class, the second class does infact have the correct code to load it (I believe as I wil post here) and it should load when called but instead on my phone I keep getting a force close, I am using intents if you look here

I only tried one button for now

```
            import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
       import android.widget.Button;
         import android.widget.LinearLayout;

            public class mainMenu extends Activity {
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;

@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  //This is calling the layout in the main.xml file if I          change the main.xml file name then I would 
       LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    lin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.letterlist);
    Button free = (Button)findViewById(R.id.freeDraw);



    Button trace = (Button)findViewById(R.id.trace);
    Button sent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sentence);




free.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick (View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), freeDraw.class); 
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
}


});

}
      }
```

Next will be the code I am trying to switch it too,   They both use the same package I already checked that.

```
      public class freeDraw extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {
private EditText words; //calling my edit text and naming it to variable words
private static final String TAG = "Gesture Revealer"; 
GestureLibrary gestureLib = null; //calling my gesture library


@Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.free);  //This is calling the layout in trace.xml for now
```

There are no errors in any of the xml files.  So my question is that what am I doing wrong with intents? (because I believe that is the problem.

But basically all I want to do is from the main menu (first code) switch when the button is pressed to free draw mode(second code).  Which brings up a whole new layout.

heres the android runtime error i got in the logcat

```
                           01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                           01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.better.work.learning.letters.and.more.awesome/com.better.work.learning.letters.and.more.awesome.freeDraw}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                      01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
```

01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1515)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2941)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at com.better.work.learning.letters.and.more.awesome.mainMenu$1.onClick(mainMenu.java:41)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please post the stack trace from the logcat when it force closes.

Comment: R.id.freeDraw is this button in your main.xml?

Comment: @Rich Talcik, try logcat because the code in the click event should work.

Comment: what am I looking for in my logcat?, and yes the R.id.freedraw is in my main.xml

Comment: Have u declare freeDraw class in Manifest file???

Comment: I do not think so how how exactly would I do that?

Comment: I figured it out thanks alot for all of your help now maybe you guys can help me understand what im doing wrong with my ads, because all I see is a red box that says "you must have AdActivity declared in androidManifest.xml with configChanges"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.better.work.learning.letters.and.more.awesome/com.better.work.learning.letters.and.more.awesome.freeDraw}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-18 03:50:48.432: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
```

This Logcat means you have not declared your second Activity in manifest file.